# Close software opened with node by spawn, exec

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

What i am trying to do is for example open visual studio code with spawn, exec, ... and get the process to close visual studio code later with node again.

With spawn i got the child_process that open visual studio code but not the visual studio itself so I can't send any signal to kill it. I could get all the process currently running and get its pid, but I would like to know if there is another way to do it with node.

This is what i have:

`let visualStudioCode = spawn('code',{detached: true});`

With code i can open visual studio code from the terminal.
I have attempted with the absolute path to visual studio code.

Thank you.

Comment: Read this carefully https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit

Comment: What do you expect from launching GUI software from node?

Comment: *With spawn i got the child_process that open visual studio code but not the visual studio itself*. There are several `code` processes, one of which is main. I'm unable to test this with Node but killing should result in closing `code` subprocesses.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers. I would like to create an electron app that start and close others apps, it is just to learn. When i use the exit event it is triggered even before i send the signal, or I am doing something wrong. I would like to know if i can do it with node or not. Thanks you so much for your time.

Comment: @alexbg you need to share some more code, otherwise I don't think anyone can answer this